# Backbone-Relational and Django-Tastypie: many-to-many fields operating example

Tags: many-to-many, tastypie, backbone-relational

May somebody provide an example of operating with many-to-many fields of django.db models' instances through django-tastypie and backbone-relational? That's possible now with using intermediate model.

```python
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)    

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books', through='Authorship')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=42)

class Authorship(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Here are possible tastypie resources' configuration:

```python
from tastypie import fields, resources

class AuthorResource(resources.NamespacedModelResource):
    books = fields.ToManyField('library.api.resources.AuthorshipResource', 'books')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'author'
        queryset = models.Author.objects.all()

class BookResource(resources.NamespacedModelResource):
    authors = fields.ToManyField('library.api.resources.AuthorshipResource', 'authors')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'book'
        queryset = models.Book.objects.all()

class AuthorshipResource(resources.NamespacedModelResource):
    author = fields.ToOneField('library.api.resources.AuthorResource', 'author')
    book = fields.ToOneField('.api.resources.BookResource', 'book')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'authorship'
        queryset = models.Authorship.objects.all()
```

How to save Author related with a few unsaved yet Books using one request to our server?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601223/django-tastypie-imlementing-many-to-many-through-relationships